# Create custom dimension if string in cell contains X

Tags: looker-studio

I'm trying to create a custom dimension in Google data studio. The dimension should check if the cell string contains a specific string and return another string.

I've been googling and I found that I need to use a case statement with regex_match but I can't tell if I've done it properly as the resulting field is getting picked up as a custom metric instead of a custom dimension

These are my campaign names:

```
bil_ May-June'19_ Tertiary Campaign_ BMM_24th May'19
bil_ May-June'19_ Category Campaign_ BMM_24th May'19
bil_ May-June'19_ Brand Campaign_ BMM_24th May'19
bil_ May-June'19_ Category Campaign_ Exact_24th May'19
bil_ May-June'19_ Brand Campaign_ Exact_24th May'19
bil_ May-June'19_ Tertiary Campaign_ Exact_24th May'19
```

This is the case statement I wrote to categorize them:

```
CASE 
    WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(CAMPAIGN,".*Tertiary.*") THEN "Tertiary"
    WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(CAMPAIGN,".*Brand.*") THEN "Brand"
    WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(CAMPAIGN,".*Category.*") THEN "Category" 
    ELSE "Other"
END
```

The expected result is a custom dimension which has only 3 rows (Tertiary, Brand, and Category). Right now I don't know if I'm doing it correctly as this field ends up in the metrics list and not the dimensions list.

Please help out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested out the [`CASE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020724) statement above, and it works as expected; ensure that the *Type* is set to *Text*, and if it's added as a *Chart-level* calculated field, add it as a *Dimension* (not a *Metric*); also, in this scenario, a single [`REGEXP_EXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7050487) function does the trick:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(CAMPAIGN, ".*(Tertiary|Brand|Category).*")
```

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/fea54a19-60ca-49ec-a327-388bc6af579e) and GIF to elaborate:

[image: 2]]